# getting issue "syntax error near unexpected token 'yes,yes' "

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

I was writing Makefile and the code was

```
ifeq($(a),YES)
echo "xp"
else
echo "yp"
fi
```

after running the script it shows

```
/bin/sh: Line 0 syntax error near unexpected token 'yes,yes'
```

Comment: You need to show us the *complete* rule/target involved here. That's not enough code for us to go on. (Nor can I see how that could cause that problem since `yes` doesn't appear anywhere in that snippet.)

Comment: Why is `/bin/sh` giving the message?  How are you running the makefile?  You need to run `make -f makefile` or an equivalent.  Or you need to show more of your code so that it is reproducible.